# Registering Windsor Component for both direct use and as an array

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I'm automatically registering multiple components that implement the same interface:

```
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(
    new ArrayResolver(container.Kernel));

container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .BasedOn<IPaymentPostProcessor>()
    .WithService.FromInterface(typeof(IPaymentPostProcessor))
    .Configure(c => c.Named(c.Implementation.Name))
    .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.PerWebRequest));
```

This works when I have a dependency on the array itself:

```
public class PaymentPostProcessorManager{
    public PaymentPostProcessorManager(IPaymentPostProcessor[] processors){}
}
```

But doesn't if I have a dependency on a specific component implementing the interface:

```
public class SpecialService{
    public OtherService(SpecificPostProcessor processor){}
}
```

This fails, it says no components have been registered for SpecificPostProcessor.  If I individually register that SpecificPostProcessor, it the array resolution ends up including it twice.

How can I do the automatic registration based on the interface AND have it automatically register it for specific dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `WithService.Self()` for your `SpecificPostProcessor` If you want to expose it as a service.

Comment: Oh no, I don't seem to have .Self() as an option using 2.1.  I've been avoiding upgrading for some time because of conflicts with other parts of the project -- it seems to break my code using rhino.esb.  Is this the only way?

Comment: I think there is `WithService.Select(you do the work here)` in v2.1